# call C++ function in lua script and load the script then call lua function

Tags: lua, oolua

C++ code:

```
void f1() {}
void f2() {}
```

LUA:

```
function t()
    f1() --defined in cpp
    f2() --defined in cpp
```

Then call t in C++:

```
OOLUA::Script vm;
vm.load_file("script.lua")
// need call t()
```

How to do this in OOLUA? I read its doc, it has complete reference, but haven't tell you how to use them in detail. And I can not find usage example by google also...

Answer (score 0):

You can call any basic lua functions by using:

```
lua.call(functionName, functionParams)
```

In your case you can just provide the function name. Also if you wish to get the return from your lua function you can call:

```
std::string result;
OOLUA::pull(lua, result);
```